Source Generator not running when using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
I have a large list of types that I need to have basic CRUD services and editors for. I intend to use Source Generators to create all of these classes at compile time based on a json file containing each type. The types are defined in TypeDefinitions.json which is included in the project as a C# Analyzer Additional File. The intention is to open this file, deserialize it with STJ, and create classes from the result.
Here is my source generator:
[Generator]
public class ServiceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        
        AdditionalText file = context.AdditionalFiles
            .First(f => Path.GetFileName(f.Path).Equals("TypeDefinitions.json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        string text = file.GetText().ToString();

        TypeDefinition typeDefinition = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TypeDefinition>(text);
    }

    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        
    }
}

TypeDefinition is defined as:
internal class TypeDefinition
{
    public List<LookupType> LookupTypes { get; set; }
}

internal class LookupType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

I am using Debugger.Launch() to step through the generator while testing it. This was working as I expected until I adde the last line to the Execute function. Once I included the use of JsonSerializer it no longer even starts debugging. The solution acts as though the source generator isn't even there, and the normal startup project just runs. If I comment out the line with JsonSerializer.Deserialize and debug it once again triggers the debugger and I'm able to debug the generator once again. It clearly appears that that line is what is causing the generator to not run, though there are no errors shown. Being a source genenerator the project targets .NET Standard 2.0 and I am referencing System.Text.Json version 4.7.2 as a NuGet package.

Are you also using source generators for System.Text.Json?  And if so have you disabled reflection-based default serialization?

@dbc Not using anything else. What I posted is the only class in the Source Generator project. Setting JsonSerializerIsReflectionEnabledByDefault to false in the csproj file had no effect.
